# create directory with timestamp in chef

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I want to create a directory from chef recipe to backup my existing artifacts. i want to create the backup directory with following format.

> appname_bkp_17-10-11-125845

for example I need to create this directory and add the directory name into a variable which is something like;

> bkp_dir_name =  appname_bkp_17-10-11-125845

Please advice.

Comment: Have you tried something? where are you stuck?

Comment: I got this.

`time = Time.now.strftime("%F-%T")`
`Dir.mkdir "#{node['default']['default_backup_path']}/appname_#{time}"`

But now my problem is how to make this directory name as a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Chef is a DSL, it is still first and foremost pure Ruby. You should try to learn a little about Ruby basics before committing to Chef entirely, because a lot of what you might want to do will be more efficient if you know the language.

```
time = Time.now.strftime("%F-%T").gsub(':','')
dir = "appname_bkp_#{time}"
path = ::File.join(node['default']['default_backup_path'], dir)

# Chef resource to create a directory with default properties
directory path
```

Comment: Thanks vase. I'm trying do something like below.

` FileUtils.cp_r Dir.glob"#{node['default']['home']}/standalone/deployments/('*.ear')", "#{node['default']['default_backup_path']}/oms_bkp_#{time}/"`

which is giving me below error. could you please help me on this?

TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer